# A-Frame GLTF models either oversaturated or washed out

Tags: blender, aframe, gltf

My setup is modelling in Blender 2.8 and texturing in Substance Painter. Finished models are exported via GLTF and loaded in A-Frame. My models looks either washed out or oversaturated and when color management is on/off.

Any idea whats wrong with my workflow?

Blender 2.80b
A-Frame 0.90
Chrome 73.0.3683.86
MacOS 10.14.3

This is my typical node setup in blender:

[image: blender node]

Here's an example with sRGB encoding in A-Frame:

[image: srgb encoding]

And one with linear encoding:

[image: linear encoding]

Finally this is the preview in Substance Painter:

[image]

Comment: What is changed between the screenshot "with sRGB encoding in A-Frame" and "with linear encoding"? Did you change encoding in A-Frame, or in Blender before export? In Blender, your base color and emissive textures should be sRGB, and everything else should be linear. In A-Frame, I'd suggest using the `renderer="colorManagement: true"` option here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/renderer.html.

Comment: (In Blender the encoding is really that dropdown "Color" vs "Non-Color" data on the Image Texture)

Comment: @DonMcCurdy. In the first screenshot the encoding on the model is set like this:

material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
material.emissiveMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

in the second it's

material.map.encoding = THREE.LinearEncoding
material.emissiveMap.encoding = THREE.LinearEncoding

Colormanagment is enabled in A-frame

Comment: Hm ok. The first is right, and should be what you see without overriding encoding in A-Frame too. The remaining differences between that and what you see in Substance Painter I'm not sure about, but could be due to the environment map partly. How does it look in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com?

Comment: This might be an easier conversation for the glTF Slack, glTF forums, or A-Frame Slack, if it's not just a simple encoding mistake. 